# I can't use gedit and can't install on Ubuntu subsystem which is installed on my windows machine

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

```
ganesh@DESKTOP-DNIP20Q:~/ganesh$ gedit                                                                                  
Unable to init server: Could not connect: 
Connection refused                                                                                                                                                                                    
(gedit:91): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:56:20.340: cannot open display:                                                          
ganesh@DESKTOP-DNIP20Q:~/ganesh$
```

Comment: You've installed ubuntu on Windows10 with WSL2 ? I don't think microsoft/windows/WSL2 already supports GUI integration - you can look here how some people work around this - https://medium.com/@japheth.yates/the-complete-wsl2-gui-setup-2582828f4577 . It might be better to install ubuntu as a VM on windows to get good gui integration or wait until WSL2/Windows officially supports integrating WSL2 guis with windows guis. Microsoft are working on it : see here https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/whats-new-in-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux-september-2020/#gui-apps

Comment: You can use a CLI editor instead of `gedit`, e.g. `nano`.

Answer (score 2):

MS/Windows/WSL2 doesn't support linux GUI integration with windows for the moment

Microsoft is working on it but it'll take another 6 months to a year (my guess) before that will be available

see MS blog : https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/whats-new-in-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux-september-2020/#gui-apps

possible workaround : install ubuntu in a VM (virtualbox maybe)

Or use some workarounds as written in https://medium.com/@japheth.yates/the-complete-wsl2-gui-setup-2582828f4577
I wouldn't recommend it as it's not officially supported by ubuntu nor microsoft